# React-Native: Workspace doesn't contain correct schema

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

So I have a react-native environment setup called "rootapp". It was working when I launched the ios Xcode simulator from my terminal with the command "react-native run-ios", but all of a sudden I'm receiving this error. What's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that you updated your react-native version at some point since that last time you ran the code? Try running `react-native upgrade` and then `react-native run-ios` again in terminal. That might help correct some discrepancies between the files from the previous version of react-native and the new version.